# inner join when the key is two columns

Tags: sql

I need to create a summary table Which is a summary of the targets and sales.
Here are the tables.

target_table

| customer_id | month | target |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 05 | 60 |
| 101 | 06 | 60 |
| 102 | 05 | 80 |
| 102 | 05 | 85 |

selse_table

| customer_id | month | selse |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 05 | 40 |
| 101 | 06 | 70 |
| 102 | 05 | 90 |
| 102 | 05 | 60 |

Here is my query

```
    CREATE TABLE SUMMERY
    AS SELECT SALSE.customrt_id, SALSE.month, SALSE.selse, targets.target
    FROM  SALSE
    Inner join TARGETS
    on SALSE.CUSTOMER_ID=TARGETS.customer_ID
```

I try to use INNER JOIN but the problem is that it is not enough for me just the customer_id column because the same customer has different destinations every month.
Is my query correct? How to do the INNER JOIN right?

Comment: You can have more than one clause in an `ON`. It's not limited to one boolean expression.

Comment: MySQL != SQL Server - please correct your tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't understand your question very well，like this?

```
on SALSE.CUSTOMER_ID=TARGETS.customer_ID and SALSE.[MONTH]=TARGETS.[MONTH]
```

Comment: Is the AND condition in addition to the first condition?
That is, first the customer and then the month ?

Comment: The conditions behind on are the same as where.